# How to improve feature layer performance with esri javascript api 4.15

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-online

I am creating a feature layer with layer url from esri online.

It currently has 250 000 data points. But with this 250k points itself it is rendering extremely slow. I also using mode on demand as

```
mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND
```

How can i improve the performance with feature layer? Any reference is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebGL:

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/mapping/mapping/featurelayer-rendering-taking-advantage-of-webgl-in-2d/

Or try to use canvas rendering instead of svg